# How to split a "\n" in java when read the data from mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, split

In my Java code I define a string `String strExample='abc\ndef'`. Now I want to split it. So I try to get the length of the string.

```
int strArrlength=strExample.split("\n").length
```

The result is 2.
But when I try to write the strExample in to mysql table, and then read it from the table, in the same code I get the length is 1.
My development environment is Windows 8.1, and the database is installed in CentOS 6.5.
What's wrong? I've tried to change the code like:

```
strExample.split("\\n"),split("\r\n"),split("\n+"),split("\\r?\\n")
```

but all of them return 1;

Here is my test,but still not work.

```
private final static String        mHexStr1="5468697320697320612074657374EFBC815C6E204F6E6C792061207465737421";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testStr=hexStr2Str(mHexStr1);
    System.out.print(testStr+";"+testStr.split("\\n").length);//return 1
    String abc="This is a test！\n Only a test!"; 
    System.out.println(abc+";"+abc.split("\n").length);//return 2
}
```

Comment: why are you using `\n` as separator? why not a bar (`|`)?

Comment: @dunli,because the content may be an essay,and it really has `\n`.

Comment: Store your short text string `abc\ndef` in your database, then, in mysql without using Java, do `SELECT HEX(<yourfield>) FROM <yourtable> WHERE <some condition that gets only that test record>` to get a hex dump of the exact character values stored in the database.  When you've got the stored data back in Java, dump the actual character values that are in the String.  This will tell you if it's stored as you expect, if it's changed when retrieving it, and what exactly you'll want to split on.

Comment: @flower I see. You need to split it to count the number of words?

Comment: @dunli,just a using example,in fact I really need to split them.You know,get the summary,get the last  section and so on.

Comment: @StephenP,I have test your suggetion,but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to select HEX content.Just replace the data  `\\n` with `\n`  which is read from mysql.